# I am using R code to count for a specific word occurrence in a string. How can I update it to count if the word's synonyms are used?

Tags: r, stringr, sapply

I'm using the following code to find if the word "assist" is used in a string variable.
`string<- c("assist")`

```
`assist <-
(1:nrow(df) %in% c(sapply(string, grep, df$textvariable, fixed = TRUE)))+0`

`sum(assist)`
```

If I also wanted to check if synonyms such as "help" and "support" are used in the string, how can I update the code? So if either of these synonyms are used, I want to code it as 1. If neither of these words are used, I want to code it as 0. It doesn't matter if all of the words appear in the string or how many times they are used.

I tried changing it to

```
string<- c("assist", "help", "support")
```

But it looks like it is searching for strings in which all of these words are used?

I'd appreciate your help!

Thank you

Comment: Likely duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35962426/multiple-strings-with-str-detect-r or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597559/grep-using-a-character-vector-with-multiple-patterns

Comment: Thank you Ian. I checked the posts you referenced and they are discussing different cases.